# Make hidden header appear on smaller screens only

Tags: html, css

So I have a website which has the header show when a arrow is hovered over with the cursor, however on a mobile it does not work very well.

I was wondering if its possible to make the header show when on a smaller device?  Could I use CSS to hide the arrow but trigger the hover event on the page loading?

Ideally I need to do this for screens around 480px, as these are when the hover has most issues on being tapped.

The header is quite simple code;

```
     <header id="header" role="banner">
<center id="showHeader">
<img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/img/a.jpg">
      <div class="headwidth">
            <h1 class="logo">
<a href="index.html" title="Outside The Line"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </h1> 
          <nav id="main-nav">
        <a href="index.html">Work</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>  

</center> 
    </header>
```

My CSS;

```
    header .container{
        position:relative !important;
    }
    center#showHeader:hover > .headwidth {
     height: 180px;
     width: 100%;
    }


    .headwidth {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
        transition: .7s;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Website Example](http://outsidetheline.co.uk)

Comment: See [CSS media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/317/media-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [EDIT]

The following code will fix your issue:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .headwidth {
    height: 180px;
  }
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ou1ugLsr/1/) for a visual representation (Try to push the screen to width less than **`480px`**).

**Snippet:**

```css
header .container {
  position: relative !important;
}

center#showHeader:hover > .headwidth {
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}

.headwidth {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: .7s;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .headwidth {
    height: 180px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header" role="banner">
  <center id="showHeader">
    <img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/img/a.jpg">
    <div class="headwidth">
      <h1 class="logo">
<a href="index.html" title="Outside The Line"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </h1>
      <nav id="main-nav">
        <a href="index.html">Work</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </center>
</header>
```

---

### [INITIAL ANSWER]

You can use **`@media`** queries in CSS to make your website scalable and responsive. **The are a lot of ways to use media queries**, but I like to use them like so:

```
.element {
    /* The code to be used for this element in general */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    .element {
        /* The code to be used for this element in devices wider than 1300px */
    }
}
```

The above example can show different content at different sizes **based on the minimum `width` of the screen of the user's device**.

Be sure to check out these pages for **info related to the correct use of media queries** as well as easily comprehensible examples:

- [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)
- [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: Hey, 

Thanks, I already use the media command, but the header is hidden, so without the hover in general it will not show, tapping does not work due to the area just not responding on some phones.. I need to know how to activate hover on a smaller screen size, so I am not sure if media would help due to the html side still hiding the header?

Comment: I tested your website on my phone and the menu shows when I tap on it. What exactly is that you want to fix?

Comment: It is fine for me too, but yet I am being told by others it is not working for them.. Tricky issue really.. so I was looking to just make it open automatically on the page load when the screen drops below a certain width

Comment: When using media queries you can tell the browser not to display the arrow and display the entire header instead. Media queries is the way to go by all means. Nice website by the way.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have some reading to do on media queries, they have saved me on other area's of this website though. thanks for the guide :)

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but oddly nothing changed.  I am wondering if the way I have done the HTML side is stopping it

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? I used the code in your question and it works.

Comment: Ah I did not see that!  Worked a charm that time, I am guessing where I place code within CSS results in how it works?  I had placed it before the headwidth section, which resulted in no change, but switching it to exactly how you had it worked.  Thanks :) huge help and really helpful knowing all of this

Comment: Glad I could help @DanielHobbs.